# How to store JSON Array as String

Tags: sql, json, user-defined-functions

I need the Function to concatenate two JSON Strings together and to insert it into one Table Column. But I do something wrong. Could You help me please?

```
create function Jsom_Merge
(
@json1 nvarchar(max),
@json2 nvarchar(max)
)
returns nvarchar(max)
as
begin

declare     @json3 nvarchar(max)

select @json3 =
FROM 
 (
    SELECT 
    FROM OPENJSON( @json1 )
    WITH
    ( IID sys.int '$.Inst[0].id',
        sidInstance           sys.NVARCHAR( 50 ) '$.Inst[1].Instances',
        DatumInstance         sys.NVARCHAR( 50 ) '$.Inst[2].Instances',
        ServerInstance        sys.NVARCHAR( 50 ) '$.Inst[3].Instances',
        VirtualServerInstance sys.NVARCHAR( 50 ) '$.Inst[4].Instances',
        OptionalInstance      sys.NVARCHAR( 50 ) '$.Inst[5].Instances'
    ) a
inner join 
   OPENJSON( @json2 )
    WITH
    ( WID sys.int '$.Value[0].id',
        CPUType               sys.NVARCHAR( 50 ) '$.Value[0].Werte',
        Frequency             sys.NVARCHAR( 50 ) '$.Value[1].Werte'
    ) b on a.IID = b.WID
) t FOR JSON PATH , INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES

return @json3

end;
```

Comment: What are the values of the `@json1` and `@json2` parameters and what is the expected output?

Comment: SET @json1 = '{"Inst":[{"id":-627706141,"Instances":"Inst22"}
,{"id":-627706141,"Instances":"20200605"}
,{"id":-627706141,"Instances":"Sometghing"}
,{"id":-627706141,"Instances":"SomeServer"}
,{"id":-627706141,"Instances":"OptionalServer"}]}'

Comment: SET @json2 = '{"Value":[{"id":-627706141,"Werte":"Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v3 "},{"id":-627706141,"Werte":" 2.60GHz"}]}'

Comment: Tose both Strings must be concatinated in one JSON Formatted String and combined with flat SQL Data (no  JSON Format)

Comment: dont forget to remove new lines from string otherwise you will lose data. when working manually you can use: https://codebeautify.org/jsonminifier

Comment: My Query with join of both strings returns exactly what I wish, but I dont know, how to insert it ito my Table

Comment: ...it trturns: [{"IID":-627706141,"sidInstance":"20200605","DatumInstance":"Sometghing","ServerInstance":"SomeServer","VirtualServerInstance":"OptionalServer","OptionalInstance":null,"WID":-627706141,"CPUType":"Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v3 ","Frequency":" 2.60GHz"}]

Comment: @IrinaKrutashova It depends on the table's structure, but your function generates a valid JSON

Comment: @Zhorov thank you. But how could I create the function to return this String. The function abowe dont works :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to fix the function definition:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Json_Merge (
   @json1 nvarchar(max),
   @json2 nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN

   DECLARE @json3 nvarchar(max)

   SELECT @json3 = (
     SELECT * 
     FROM (
       SELECT *
       FROM OPENJSON( @json1 )
       WITH
       ( IID sys.int '$.Inst[0].id',
           sidInstance           sys.NVARCHAR( 50 ) '$.Inst[1].Instances',
           DatumInstance         sys.NVARCHAR( 50 ) '$.Inst[2].Instances',
           ServerInstance        sys.NVARCHAR( 50 ) '$.Inst[3].Instances',
           VirtualServerInstance sys.NVARCHAR( 50 ) '$.Inst[4].Instances',
           OptionalInstance      sys.NVARCHAR( 50 ) '$.Inst[5].Instances'
       ) a
       inner join 
       OPENJSON( @json2 )
       WITH
       ( WID sys.int '$.Value[0].id',
           CPUType               sys.NVARCHAR( 50 ) '$.Value[0].Werte',
           Frequency             sys.NVARCHAR( 50 ) '$.Value[1].Werte'
       ) b on a.IID = b.WID
     ) t
     FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
   )

   RETURN @json3
END
```

Execution:

```
SELECT dbo.Json_Merge (
   '{"Inst":[{"id":-627706141,"Instances":"Inst22"} ,{"id":-627706141,"Instances":"20200605"} ,{"id":-627706141,"Instances":"Sometghing"} ,{"id":-627706141,"Instances":"SomeServer"} ,{"id":-627706141,"Instances":"OptionalServer"}]}',
   '{"Value":[{"id":-627706141,"Werte":"Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v3 "},{"id":-627706141,"Werte":" 2.60GHz"}]}'
)
```